# rsync dry run not showing differences

Tags: ssh, ftp, rsync

I'm copying some directories between 2 remote servers (using FileZilla).  To make sure everything had copied correctly, I wanted to use `rsync` to make sure there were no differences.

FileZilla had reported one file transfer error (the file in question wasn't copied, and I confirmed this by `ls`), so I was expecting `rsync` to show that this file didn't exist on the destination server.  However, `rsync` doesn't report any differences.

Some relevant output:

> ```
> chris@server1$ ls -l Tan*
> -rw-r--r-- 1 chris people 841991 Aug 19  2009 Tan&Thorpe_1992.pdf
> ```

> ```
> chris@server2 ls -l Tan*
> -rw------- 1 chris ppl 1006306 Aug 19  2009 Tan*
> -rw------- 1 chris ppl 1006306 Dec 24 16:02 Tan.test.pdf
> -rw------- 1 chris ppl  841991 Aug 19  2009 Tan&Thorpe_1992.pdf
> ```

> ```
> chris@server1$ rsync -nvci * chris@server2:/home/chris/mydocuments/
> chris@server2's password:
> skipping directory Pictures
>
> sent 35035 bytes  received 12 bytes  3337.81 bytes/sec
> total size is 923703254  speedup is 26356.13 (DRY RUN)
> ```

I have tried various options on `rsync` (`-c`, `-i`), but can't get the differences to be displayed.  Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong would be highly appreciated (or equally, any better alternatives to what I'm trying to achieve)!

**more info**

I've gone and looked at the original file, and tried downloading it via FileZilla again.  When I do, I see the following in `filezilla.log`

```
2015-12-24 19:39:01 10652 1 Status: Starting download of /home/chris/mydocuments/Tan
2015-12-24 19:39:01 10652 1 Command: mtime "Tan"
2015-12-24 19:39:01 10652 1 Error: get attrs for /home/chris/mydocuments/Tan: no such file or directory
2015-12-24 19:39:01 10652 1 Command: get "Tan" "/home/chris/mydocuments/Tan"
2015-12-24 19:39:01 10652 1 Error: /home/chris/mydocuments/Tan: open for read: no such file or directory
2015-12-24 19:39:01 10652 1 Error: File transfer failed
```

...but the file **does** exist - I can `cp` it, `mv` it, list it, etc... this seems a bit weird to me, but might help to explain why `rsync` is ignoring it?

Comment: I always use the `-a` option, which ensures that rsync actually copies something.

Comment: Does this not defeat the point of the `-n` option, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: `-n` overrides; some part of `-a` seems to be needed to make rsync find files to copy.  (It is not obvious from the manpage, but I've found this by use...).